# Python User Input Average

Tags: python, input, average

I'm trying to work on a school assignment that asks the user to input 3 integers, then I need to pass these three integers as parameters to a function named **avg** that will return the average of these three integers as a float value.

Here's what I've come up with so far, but I get this error:

```
line 13, in <module>
    print (average)
NameError: name 'average' is not defined
```

Advice?

```
    a = float(input("Enter the first number: "))
    b = float(input("Enter the second number: "))
    c = float(input("Enter the third number: "))

    def avg(a,b,c):
        average = (a + b + c)/3.0
        return average


    print ("The average is: ")
    print (average)

    avg()
```

Comment: "print" is a statement, not a function. You should not use parenthesis around what you want to print.

Comment: @jrennie OP did not specify if this was Python 2.x or 3.x, but if this is Python 3, print is indeed a function and requires parentheses

Comment: @Cyber Doh! Sorry for showing off my ignorance of 3.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`average` only exists as a local variable inside the function `avg`

```
def avg(a,b,c):
    average = (a + b + c)/3.0
    return average

answer = avg(a,b,c) # this calls the function and assigns it to answer

print ("The average is: ")
print (answer)
```

Comment: I can see where I went wrong with not passing the variables.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should `print(avg(a,b,c))` because the `average` variable is only stored in the function and cannot be used outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

1. You called avg without passing variables to it.
2. You printed average which is only defined inside the avg function.
3. You called avg after your print.

Change `print (average)` to

```
average = avg(a, b, c);
print(average)
```